# AppCompat Snackbar not centered on tablet

Tags: android, material-design, android-appcompat

I'm trying to show a snackbar (via appcompat) to display a message to the user. It works perfectly fine on phones, however on tablets I'm getting

[image: portrait]

and

[image: landscape]

The code I'm using to generate the snackbar is

```
Snackbar.make(mHomeContainer, R.string.rate_snackbar, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Rate", ...)
        .show();
```

Any guidance on how to make this snackbar centered would be greatly appreciated

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/status_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/main"
        android:elevation="8dp"/>

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/home_search_list"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#88000000"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<include layout="@layout/navigation_list" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Snacker should not be full width on tablet/desktop according to [this](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-specs).

Comment: thanks, Ive updated it to say centered instead of full width

Comment: What is `mHomeContainer`? Does `mHomeContainer` fill the entire width of the screen?

Comment: Its a full width RelativeLayout

Comment: Post your tablet layout

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti added the full layout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the CoordinatorLayout in order to make this happen. Here is an [article](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/) that describes how to do that. Additionally you will likely need to now provide layout files that you want to use for non-tablets vs. tablets so that you can retain full-width for your phones. This is also the layout component that you need to use if you use a combination of FAB, app bar and Snackbar.

Comment: What if I have nested fragments in some fragment - one at the left and one at the right. And on click some item on the left I'd like to show a snackbar at the bottom center of a window? I have to add coordinator layout in the parent fragment at the bottom and on click some item I have to pass to the parent fragment call that snack bar should be shown? Not very useful, though

Comment: That seems like you'd be breaking away from general Material Design principals in doing this. Perhaps the message should be within the fragment or is this something that Toast is better for, depending on what you're trying to accomplish? I haven't tried to use multiple CoordinatorLayouts, but perhaps that is possible for you?

Answer (score 4):

In v22.2.0 of Design Support Library, Snackbar's default gravity was just Gravity.BOTTOM.

In v22.2.1 this issue was fixed: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176383